# Plotting a graph in C (ubuntu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, plot, graph

i would like to ask a question,because i have been searching for 2 hours.

I have a project in a game development course and i have arrays of some map elements,positions,and lines that connect them.And i need to draw a graph from them.But I don't have the slightest idea.Do i include some header file?

Do i download that? If i had the commands i could work with that,but i don't see graphics command anywhere in code blocks.

Please inform me on what i can use to draw a simple graph,and possibly the installation process in general if it's not too much trouble

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing as a *"graphics command"* somewhere in Code::Blocks. In order to create graphical interfaces and to be able to draw things, you have to use a **GUI library** (like GTK, Qt, SFML, wx... etc).

Since your requirement is to use C I'd recommand you then to go with [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/). Since it's one of the best and most documented library with C language at it's base.

**Note:** Please be careful that what I mentioned above are **only** GUI libraries, *i.e.* mainly used to create graphical user interfaces. Since you are following a game development course, you may rather want to take a look at game engines such as SDL or Unity, which are quite different things, and enable to perform a lot more (serious) gaming stuff.

[Here's a Wikipedia list with a thorough listing of GUI libraries.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries)

Comment: thank you for the answer but i my main goal is displaying a simple 2d graph.Not sure if i can do it with a GUI library?

Comment: Use SDL. [Here's a nice tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzFAZK9RUMk)